# Parcelable nested class with map property crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I have two parcelable clsses:

```
    class MyDevice implements Parcelable{
        @SerializedName("DeviceName")
        public String DeviceName;

        @SerializedName("StolenFlag")
        public Boolean StolenFlag;

        @SerializedName("BatteryLevel")
        public int BatteryLevel;


        @SerializedName("LastLocalization")
        public Map<String,Geography> LastLocalization;


        protected MyDevice(Parcel in) {
            DeviceName = in.readString();
            BatteryLevel = in.readInt();
            StolenFlag = in.readByte() !=0;
            LastLocalization = in.readParcelable(Geography.class.getClassLoader());
        }

....
        @Override
         public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(DeviceName);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (StolenFlag ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeInt(BatteryLevel);
        dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization.get("Geography"), 0);
    }
    }
```

And second:

```
class Geography implements Parcelable{

    @SerializedName("CoordinateSystemId")
    public int CoordinateSystemId;

    @SerializedName("WellKnownText")
    public String WellKnownText;

    protected Geography(Parcel in) {
        CoordinateSystemId = in.readInt();
        WellKnownText = in.readString();
    }


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(CoordinateSystemId);
        dest.writeString(WellKnownText);
    }
}
```

Putting it into intent is fine. When I try to get it from the intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<MyDevice> MyDevicesList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");
```

My app crashes and gives error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andrev.lab3/com.example.andrev.lab3.SecondActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.andrev.lab3.Geography cannot be cast to java.util.Map`

I suppose that I should modify MyDevice or Geography protected constructors, but I have no idea how. Can anyone help me with that? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
LastLocalization = in.readParcelable(Geography.class.getClassLoader());
```

You are reading a parcelable of type `Geography` and trying to assign it to a field of type `Map`.

You should modify it to something like this:

```
Geography geography = in.readParcelable(Georgraphy.class.getClassLoader());
LastLocalization = new HashMap<>();
LastLocalization.put("Geography", geography);
```

It's basically reversing your actions from `writeToParcel()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got it. The question is, do I really have to implement all Map methods as like android studio wants me to do? I can not just create `LastLocalization = new Map<>();`, becouse it calls me to implement overrided methods.

Comment: @laik My bad. You should a concrete implementation of the `Map` interface, like `HashMap`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I made a mistake in code, but your solution works! You are the man, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are writing an instance of `Geography`:

```
dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization.get("Geography"), 0);
```

You are attempting to read a `Map<String, Geography>`:

```
LastLocalization = in.readParcelable(Geography.class.getClassLoader());
```

These are not the same thing.

If you want the restored `MyDevice` to contain the full `LastLocalization` map, you should have:

```
dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization, 0);
```

Comment: Pay attention that in MyDevice property LastLocalization is `public Map<String,Geography> LastLocalization;`, when I try to put this `dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization, 0);` I get an error saying that it found Map<String, Geography> and required is Parcelable.

Comment: @laik: OK, then you may need to iterate over all the entries and write them out, then restore them that way. Regardless, what you write and what you read has to match, and what you presently have does not match.